# How to get seventh number ''drop"from drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop value of a column in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in database which have following value 
 drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop

and I want to get 7th number drop from this value.
I not want to split the string.

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name , ms sql server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, without knowing the RDBMS .. how did you suggested a solution? Strange!!!

Answer (score -1):

select 
 substr('drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop',instr('drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop#drop','drop',1,7),4) as "Drop7th"
from dual;

Comment: SQL Server, not Oracle.